# Keyboard macros for X and/or KDE

Tags: xorg, kde, keyboard

I'm looking for a utility to record and playback keyboard macros in X applications (KDE specifically). I've tried `xmacrorec` and `xmacroplay`, but after running them, my mouse and keyboard does not respond properly *(i.e. the left mouse button gets stuck in a "clicked" state)* and I have to restart X.

Are the any modern alternatives that work under **KDE 4.5** and **openSUSE 11.3**?

Comment: I am using xdotool also like `xdotool key ctrl+v`, just do not use the --delay option as it causes trouble, better use `sleep` between xdotool calls

Answer (score 6):

KDE has a program called KHotkey.  It's hard to find in the OS, slow and hard to set up and test macros... but it works well once you get the macros working.  I used it for years but once I tried [Autokey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey) I dumped it.

Both work system wide.  Autokey is written in python and you can add python scripts to your macro with no problem. There is an [Autokey discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/autokey-users).

If you use any version of Ubuntu, you can install from this [Autokey PPA](https://launchpad.net/~cdekter/+archive/ppa), instructions on how to do the install are on the web page.

Make sure you install vs 0.71.1 or later.  Earlier versions have problems with using the shift key to create hotkeys.

Comment: can they record? I installed autokey but couldnt find a way to record key strokes :(. Also, autokey seems to require python knowledge... I am sticking with xdotool for now.